# Azure Terraform API Management Graphql Support

Tags: azure, graphql, terraform, azure-api-management

I'm creating APIs on the Azure APIM with GraphQL. This is still on preview so until now I only can create them clicking in the portal or using the Azure API Rest with a PUT request.

I'm trying to migrate all of this to Terraform but I don't find any website with information about if there is any way to create GraphQL APIs with Terraform or even using a module.

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management" "example" {
  name                = "example-apim"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  publisher_name      = "My Company"
  publisher_email     = "company@terraform.io"

  sku_name = "Developer_1"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "example" {
  name                = "example-api"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "Example API"
  path                = "example"
  protocols           = ["https"]

  import {
    content_format = "graphql-file"
    content_value  = "schema.graphql"
  }
}
```

I'm kind of newbie at Terraform and I'm a little lost as I can't find any doc about this on the official page or anywhere.

EDIT: What I'm trying to find is to automate with Terraform this process:
[GraphQL Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/graphql-api)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Here is the Plugin provider of GraphQL API resources using terraform.

This provider has several configuration inputs.
In most cases, only `url` & `headers` are used,

```
provider "graphql" {
  url = "https://your-graphql-server-url"
  headers = {
    "header1" = "header1-value"
    "header2" = "header2-value"
    ...
  }
}
```

- Here is the Argument [Reference document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/sullivtr/graphql/latest/docs#full-documentation) for GraphQl API with terraform.
- And here is the complete [document](https://sullivtr.github.io/terraform-provider-graphql/docs/provider.html) for creating GraphQL api with terraform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think this is not what I meant.
What I'm trying to do is using terraform for automate this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/graphql-api
As it is on preview seems like there isn't Terraform support for that yet.

Answer (score 0):

A passthrough GraphQL API can be implemented by utilizing the [api_type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api#api_type) attribute in terraform.

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "this" {
  name                = "example-api"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "Example API"
  path                = "example"
  protocols           = ["https"]
  api_type            = "graphql"
  service_url         = "https://swapi-graphql.azure-api.net/graphql" 
}
```

- `service_url` - creates the Webservice URL from which Azure usually fetches the schema.