# Azure APIM import graphql api

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management, azure-cli

Azure APIM now support graphql passthrough (GA in last Build). This is fine but still no documentation on how it can be imported programmatically. We are doing it manually via Portal once Terraform has created the APIM. We had a look at cli but no support yet as shown in below command.

```
az apim api import --path
                   --resource-group
                   --service-name
                   --specification-format {OpenApi, OpenApiJson, Swagger, Wadl, Wsdl}
```

Is there any way we can import this via terraform ? local-exec through ps script.

Comment: [Azure Terraform API Management Graphql Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71908570/azure-terraform-api-management-graphql-support), [spacelift_azure_integration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/spacelift-io/spacelift/latest/docs/resources/azure_integration) and [Spacelift Terraform provider](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spacelift-io/terraform-provider-spacelift@v0.0.1#section-readme)

Comment: Already an open issue on GitHub: [GraphQL APIM Azure CLI Support](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/20863)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT : Yes, I have a commented there a few days ago but there hasn't been any update. Doing it manually for now but looking to have something soon

Answer (score 1):

we'll need to add the Graphql specification-format to the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/apim/api?view=azure-cli-latest#az-apim-api-import

we do support the creation of a GraphQL Api and the upload of a GraphQL Schema in cli using the below method, which may serve as a work around.

az apim api create --service-name MyApim -g MyResourceGroup --api-id MyGraphqlApi --path '/mygraphqlapi' --display-name 'My GraphQL API' --api-type **graphql**

az apim api schema create --service-name MyApim -g MyResourceGroup --api-id MyApi --schema-id **graphql** --schema-type **application/vnd.ms-azure-apim.graphql.schema** --schema-path **c:\path\to\schema.gql**

Comment: Thanks, it works. 
For all, I am using local-exec to get this work in Terraform